# Jquery - hide content in article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code:

```
<article class="about">
            <header>
                <div class="hed"></div>
            </header>

            <div class="contentt"><content>

            </content></div>
</article>
```

and this js:

```
$(".hed").unbind("click").click(function(){
        $(".contentt", this).hide();
    }
```

I need hide class contentt, when I click on class hed, but I have more article, so I need hide that with using classes. Some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.contentt` is not a descendant of `.hed`, so your approach won't work. Here is the better way:

```
$('.hed').unbind('click').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('article').find('.contentt').hide();
});
```

Here the script gets the *closest* `article` parent and finds the `.contentt` block in it's descendants.